# Opening CabInfo with a path containing whitespaces

Tags: c#, wix

I am trying to open a *.cab file (as used by a Microsoft Installer) using

```
  String cabFileName = @"C:\Programme und Einstellungen\somefolder\mycab.cab";
  CabInfo cab = new CabInfo(cabFileName);
```

The class CabInfo is part of the Windows Installer XML (WiX) toolset (cf. http://codesupport.wordpress.com/tag/microsoft-deployment-compression-cab-dll/)

However, CabInfo won't accept a file path containing white spaces, even if it's correctly escaped as shown above.

I was wondering whether there is a possibility to pass a file name containing white spaces to the CabInfo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I almost hate to suggest this, but have you tried with the 8.3 compatibility filename?  Eg:

```
CabInfo cab = new CabInfo(@"C:\PROGRA~1\somefolder\mycab.cab");
```

Unfortunately, if this mechanism works, I don't think there's a `ShortName` property on `FileInfo`.  I think you'll need to PInvoke the `GetShortPathName` function in `kernel32.dll`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is possible but I see 2 possibilities to workaround the problem :

1) .cab files are often compressed with zip file format. You could open it using a library like zlib.

2) if the file is not too big, you could copy it to a folder like "c:\temp" before opening it.

I hope it will help you.